# How to convert an array to a dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, dictionary

I have a string array that I want to convert to a `Dictionary` using *Linq*.
I want elements with a ***even index*** (including zero) to be **keys** and elements with an ***odd index*** to be **values** in the dictionary. I created a dictionary using a `for loop`:

```
string[] arr = new string[4];
arr[0] = "John";
arr[1] = "A";
arr[2] = "Luke";
arr[3] = "B";

Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i += 2)
{
    myDict.Add(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
}

//myDict -> { { "John", "A" },{"Luke","B"} }
```

And now I am curious how to do it with *LINQ* `ToDictionary()`:

```
myDict = arr.ToDictionary();
```

Comment: Did you check `ToDictionary`'s syntax? You need to combine name and letter first. After that, it's easy

Comment: Simple answer is **you cannot**. You would have to create an object or something like `{ Name = "John", Something = "A" }` and then use `ToDictionary()` on an array of these elements like : `arr.ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a.Something);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put it like this (in case of *Linq* we can exploit `Enumerable.Range` as a loop):

```
string[] arr = new string[] {
  "John", "A",
  "Luke", "B",
}  

var myDict = Enumerable
  .Range(0, arr.Length / 2)
  .ToDictionary(i => arr[2 * i], 
                i => arr[2 * i + 1]); 

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myDict));
```

Outcome:

```
[John, A]
[Luke, B]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can group by index divided by 2. Try this code:

```
string[] arr = new string[4];
arr[0] = "John";
arr[1] = "A";
arr[2] = "Luke";
arr[3] = "B";

var dict = arr.Select((s, i) => new {s, i})
    .GroupBy(x => x.i / 2)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.First().s, g => g.Last().s);
```